# Read certain values inside a JSON array without using foreach (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, decode

I've had a few problems recently trying to decode and read the price for particular items in the bitskins api.

For example: The OPSKINS API simply outputs:

`{"status":1,"time":1477116462,"response":{"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)":{"price":802,"quantity":25}`

Which is fairly easy to decode through the code:

`['response'][$name]['price']`

However the BitSkins API outputs in a fairly odd manner:

`{"status" : "success","prices" : [{"market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)","price" : "8.51","created_at" : 1477110433}`

As you can see, the price is in the same array as the item name. I was wondering how to (in PHP) to decode the API so I'm just reading the item price corresponding to the name in the same manner I did with the OPSkins API.

Thanks!

Comment: Thats not valid JSON, so please check you have not missed anything from that string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JSON String is really this, which makes it valid

```
$s = '{"status" : "success",
       "prices" : [
            {"market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
             "price" : "8.51",
            "created_at" : 1477110433}
            ]}';


$j = json_decode($s);
echo $j->prices[0]->price;
```

Or if you prefer to convert perfectly good objects to arrays

```
$j = json_decode($s, true);
echo $j['prices'][0]['price'];
```